# Format Issue, output isn't lining up

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a format issue and not sure how to fix it.

Basically the output I get is:

```
ID  Name       Price    Quantity
1   Coke       £0.70    5
2   Fanta      £0.60    5
3   Galaxy     £1.20    5
4   Snickers       £1.00    5
5   Dairy Milk     £1.30    5
```

and I'm looking everything to line up properly.

This is the code that I have:

```
    public void itemList() {
    VendItem[] itemList = stock;

    System.out.println("List All Items");
    System.out.println("++++++++++++++\n");
    System.out.println("ID\t" + "Name\t   " + "Price\t" + "Quantity");
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {

        System.out.print(i + 1 + "\t");
        System.out.print(itemList[i].getName() +"\t   ");

        System.out.printf("£%.2f", itemList[i].getPrice());
        System.out.print("\t");
        System.out.print(itemList[i].getQty() +"\n");
    }
```

Comment: for each column based on the maximum character that appears in each column calculate and based on that if you append space it will work

Comment: or you can see a similar question has been answered https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213208/printing-out-a-table-in-console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a little tip. Since you're creating a table with a header describing each column, format that header first to the way you like the table to be displayed. This will basically give you a really good idea how to format all your data that will be displayed within that table (some minor enhancements might be applied).

Rather than just printing your Header line and separating your column names with whitespaces (**" "**) or Tabs (**"\t"**) {heaven forebid}, use the [String#format()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format) method instead. I say the [String#format()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format) method instead of the [Console#printf()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-console-printf-method) method because we want the header length later for creating the underline beneath that Header. Here is an example:

```
String header = String.format("%-6s %-15s %-10s %-4s", "ID", "Name", "Price", "Quantity");
System.out.println(header);
// Underline Header. Using the String#join() method for this.
System.out.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "=")));
```

The Console output will look something like:

```
ID     Name            Price      Quantity
==========================================
```

That looks pretty good, we'll use that. To create the Header underline we use the [String#join()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-join) method along with the [Collections#nCopies()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-collections-ncopies-method) method.

Now its time to display the table data beneath the Header in the very same format. To do this use only **'one' printf()** within your **for** loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-6d %-15s £%-10.2f %-4d%n", 
                      itemList.get(i).id, 
                      itemList.get(i).name,
                      itemList.get(i).price,
                      itemList.get(i).quantity);
}
```

Notice how the *format string* used within the **printf()** method is identical to the *format string* used within the **String#format()** method with the exception that the **printf()**'s format string also contains the [**%n**](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format) tag. The tag is used to generate a platform-specific line separator since we want the next iteration of the **for** loop to be printed on a new line within the console window. With the data you provided in your post, the output to console should look something like this:

```
ID     Name            Price      Quantity
==========================================
1      Coke            £0.70       5   
2      Fanta           £0.60       5   
3      Galaxy          £1.20       5   
4      Snickers        £1.00       5   
5      Dairy Milk      £1.30       5
```

That looks okay but it would be nice if the Quantity value was a little more centered under the Header name 'Quantity'. This can be done by tweaking the overall spacing for the tag use to denote 'Price' so as to make it a wee bit wider. Just add 2 to that format string tag to make it **12** instead of **10**, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-6d %-15s £%-12.2f %-4d%n", 
                      itemList.get(i).id, 
                      itemList.get(i).name,
                      itemList.get(i).price,
                      itemList.get(i).quantity);
}
```

Now the output will look like:

```
ID     Name            Price      Quantity
==========================================
1      Coke            £0.70         5   
2      Fanta           £0.60         5   
3      Galaxy          £1.20         5   
4      Snickers        £1.00         5   
5      Dairy Milk      £1.30         5
```

There you go. You may have noticed that the data I've been iterating over is contained within a collection. I think the use of an ArrayList or List Interface is a better route to take instead of an array since these lists can grow as needed rather than needing to be pre-initialize to a specific size like an Array.

Here is the **VendItem** class I used for these demos:

```
import java.util.Collections;

public class VendItem {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float price;
    private int quantity;
    public static String HEADER = getHeader();

    public VendItem() { }

    public VendItem(int id, String name, float price, int quantity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", price=" + price + ", quantity=" + quantity;
    }

    private static String getHeader() {
        HEADER = String.format("%-6s %-15s %-10s %-4s", "ID", "Name", "Price", "Quantity") + 
                        System.lineSeparator();
        HEADER += String.join("", Collections.nCopies(HEADER.length(), "="));
        return HEADER;
    }

    public String toFormattedString() {
        return  String.format("%-6d %-15s £%-12.2f %-4d", id, name, price, quantity);
    }
}
```

And here is the code I used to display the demos:

```
List<VendItem> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
itemList.add(new VendItem(1, "Coke", 0.70f, 5));
itemList.add(new VendItem(2, "Fanta", 0.60f, 5));
itemList.add(new VendItem(3, "Galaxy", 1.20f, 5));
itemList.add(new VendItem(4, "Snickers", 1.00f, 5));
itemList.add(new VendItem(5, "Dairy Milk", 1.30f, 5));
// Display Title
System.out.println("List All Items");
System.out.println("++++++++++++++");
System.out.println()

// Display Table Header.
String header = String.format("%-6s %-15s %-10s %-4s", "ID", "Name", "Price", "Quantity");
System.out.println(header);
// Underline the Header.
System.out.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "=")));

// Display Table Data...
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-6d %-15s £%-12.2f %-4d%n", 
                      itemList.get(i).id, 
                      itemList.get(i).name,
                      itemList.get(i).price,
                      itemList.get(i).quantity);
}
```

> **EDIT: Just another thought:**

You could make your **VendItem** class return a Header and formatted data strings like a **toString()** method. The provided class already contained a **toString()** method but if you added a **toFormatedString()** method then is makes the display to console so much easier. I've added a **HEADER** Field to the class and a **toFormattedString()**. With these additional class items your table can be displayed to console like this:

```
List<VendItem> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
itemList.add(new VendItem(1, "Coke", 0.70f, 5));
itemList.add(new VendItem(2, "Fanta", 0.60f, 5));
itemList.add(new VendItem(3, "Galaxy", 1.20f, 5));
itemList.add(new VendItem(4, "Snickers", 1.00f, 5));
itemList.add(new VendItem(5, "Dairy Milk", 1.30f, 5));

System.out.println("List All Items");
System.out.println("++++++++++++++");
System.out.println();

System.out.println(VendItem.HEADER);
for (VendItem item : itemList) {
    System.out.println(item.toFormattedString());
}
```

Much easier isn't it.